# Launch .exe with html link [firefox]

Tags: javascript, php, html, firefox

I am currently developing an application in php / js / html and I would like to launch an application made in C # via a html button (no download) however I use Mozilla Firefox and the only solution I found is a script featuring `ActiveXObject` which is only used by IE apparently.

Comment: Browsers will not let you execute arbitrary files/programs on a user's computer - that'd be extremely insecure. Consider having your program register a [URI scheme](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/294588/what-is-a-uri-scheme) and then using a link with that scheme. This is how `mailto:` links are able to open your email client, for example.

Comment: also , what can I do to open my exe ? I really want a link between my .exe and my web app

Comment: Is "Browsers will not let you execute arbitrary files/programs on a user's computer" not clear enough? Joe Clay's comments seems all you need.

Comment: very well but I'm looking for a solution to run my .exe you do not help me by saying that Frederico

Comment: That's like being taught the laws of thermodynamics and then saying, "*You are not helping me build my perpetual motion machine*".

Comment: ok I watched the url sheme but when I run a .exe in the url he download himself after I click

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Firefox command line options of -url

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -url "https:\\www.stackoverflow.com"
```

or 
Use selenium Webdriver, this can launch the browser to any url you specify and can fill any form on the page with any details you specify and press any buttons that you can find.

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;

class HelloSelenium
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver())
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.stackoverflow.com/ncr");
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("Vote Up" + Keys.Enter);
        }
    }
}
```